# Static analysis tool to detect endless loop due to type promotion?

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, static-analysis

I just found this interesting bug in the deserialization routine of a complex data structure:

```
int32_t nrElements;
buffer->deserialize( &nrElements );
for( int16_t i=0; i<nrElements; ++i ) {
    // deserialize element
}
```

This works nicely if `nrElements` is smaller than 2<sup>15</sup>, but results in an infinite loop otherwise. Are there static analysis tools that can detect this sort of bug? GCC didn't warn about it.

Comment: Why the downvote and the close vote? I found this bug easy to miss when reading the code. So tool support for detecting this type of bug would be great. Are questions about static analysis tools off-topic for stackoverflow?

Comment: Yes, they are unfortunately. But they're not on [softwarerecs.stackexchange.com](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Why use `int16_t` ? For *computations* better use larger types. And perhaps even `size_t` for any size-related data.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes, of course, the bug here was exactly that `int16_t` was used instead of a larger type. I suspect that earlier `nrElements` was also a smaller type (to make the serialized format smaller), but when it was changed, the loop variable wasn't changed to match. So my question is essentially if there is an automated way to catch this type of bug.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think GCC has support for warning about this. I guess you could achieve this using a template function and static assertion:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
bool safeLess(T1 left, T2 right)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<T1, T2>::value);
    return left < right;
}
```

However, I really doubt the usefulness of this as it clutters the code (and probably gets in the way of some compiler optimizations).